# How to return card from deck

Tags: javascript, arrays, return, prompt, card

I am a beginner in Javascript and right now I am trying to figure out how to return a card by inserting a number/position. I have created an array that represents the deck but I have trouble with coding how to return a card by inserting a number in the prompt.
Do you have a suggestion on how to approach the issue?

```js
function deckBuilder() {
  const values = [
    "A",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
    "10",
    "J",
    "Q",
    "K",
  ];
  const suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"];
  const cards = [];

  for (let s = 0; s < suits.length; s++) {
    for (let v = 0; v < values.length; v++) {
      const value = values[v];
      const suit = suits[s];
      cards.push({
        value,
        suit
      });
    }
  }
  return cards;
}


let kortnummer = parseInt(prompt("Which card would yu like to see?"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Random Playing Card</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="showcard"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Give us examples of valid input into the prompt.

Comment: If I console.log(deckBuilder()); then I get 52 items ```0: {value: "A", suit: "Hearts"}
1: {value: "2", suit: "Hearts"}
2: {value: "3", suit: "Hearts"}``` and so forth. So I think that if I could insert a number, for ex. 1 I could get "2 Hearts"

Comment: Yes I realise - I'm asking for examples of valid input the user should enter into the prompt. What format does that take? How are you going to validate the input?

Comment: `const d = deckBuilder();  console.log(d[1]);`